# Google Sheets - Pulling Row Data from Left

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18zC42dPS_24YmzoNhHguMkTkX71RVaU91IaXf-zvnhs/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to come up with formula either through Query or some other function to pull Data of past 4 weeks based on the week selected.

For example in sheet 2, I have selected Week 8/28/2023, it shall pull data of that week and 3 weeks prior as highlighted in Sheet 2 from Sheet 1.

QUERY doesn't seem to work as it will only have the Column specified in Select statement and I need to make it dymanic.

Tried with FILTER and was able to pull the values (Col L - O)
`=FILTER(Sheet1!$A2:$AC2,Sheet1!$A$1:$AC$1<=$D$3)`

But FILTER doesn't quite work rigth as I only want 4 weeks data to be pulled and as values get added it'll pull more than 4 weeks data.

Answer (score 0):

If FILTER grabs the correct data, you can add a new statement to filter higher to that date -28:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!$A2:$AC2,Sheet1!$A$1:$AC$1<=$D$3,Sheet1!$A$1:$AC$1>=($D$3-28))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way around with Query by adding new transposed data and by adding start and end week. Although for this to work we will have to select week twice but I couldn't find any other easy way to do this xD

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Sheet3!1:1000,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND A>=DATE """&TEXT(D3,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" AND A<=DATE """&TEXT(D4,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""""))
```